# How to upload multiple csv file at a time in jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I am developing a web application,in that I have to upload multiple .csv files like

```
 pname   pcode     browsefile

|    |  |    |    browsefile...
|    |  |    |    browsefile...
|    |  |    |    browsefile...

        submit
```

This is how form look and when I click on submit for each csv file has to create table 
     with name of "pname".

Comment: so have you tried adding multiple file input tags in you jsp?  Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Servlet 3.0` with MultipartConfig annotation. Use `Collection<Part> getParts()` in doPost() method of servlet.

Get help from this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html).